# Can I use pthread_sigmask without thread?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I have shared code for two executable that is using pthread_sigmask. One of the executable has pthread threads the other is just one process. Is it ok to call pthread_sigmask without thread or should I use sigprocmask in the second case?

Comment: You always have threads. If you "don't have threads" then you have one thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [posix pthread_sigmask](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_sigmask.3.html):

> The pthread_sigmask() function shall examine or change (or both) the
>   calling thread's signal mask, regardless of the number of threads in
>   the process. The function shall be equivalent to sigprocmask(),
>   without the restriction that the call be made in a single-threaded
>   process.
>
> In a single-threaded process, the sigprocmask() function shall examine
>   or change (or both) the signal mask of the calling thread.

From [sigprocmask](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/sigprocmask.html):

> In a single-threaded process, the sigprocmask() function allows the calling process to examine or change (or both) the signal mask of the calling thread.
>
> .....
>
> The use of the sigprocmask() function is unspecified in a multi-threaded process.

At the start, each process has one thread, the one that runs `main()`. The `sigprocmask()` can be run only in single-threaded process. `pthread_sigmask()` can be run in any-number-of-threaded process.

> Can I use pthread_sigmask without thread?

Yes.

> Is it ok to call pthread_sigmask without thread or should I use sigprocmask in the second case?

It's ok.

You tagged `linux`. Most `linux` use `glibc`, and in `glibc` [pthread_sigmask()](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/pthread_sigmask.c.html) calls the same syscall `rt_sigprocmask` or just the function [sigprocmask()](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/pthread_sigmask.c.html). So on `glibc` they do exactly the same thing.